# apache proxy listening on multiple ports

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, tomcat

I'm using apache to proxy my tomcat instance, and I would like apache to listen on both ports 80 and 8080. I have the given configuration. But when I try to start up I get the following error:

`(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down`

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080

Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:8080 *:80>

   <Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to get apache to basically proxy all requests on 80 and 8080?

Comment: Looks like you have another program already running listening on port 80. Linux? Try this to find out what it is: netstat -lnptu

Comment: Oh right, apache is actually running on port 80. oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

This error message means that there is something already listening on the port. On linux, the following command can give you the data as to what is listening.

```
netstat -lnptu
```

Comment: Yep, thanks. Forgot apache itself was running on 80