# Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy, Multiple ports, One Server, Multiple context roots

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

Hello everyone and thanks for looking at my post! :)

**My Problem**

I am trying to setup a reverse proxy for one server listening on multiple ports for two different context roots. Only allowing connections from specific IP addresses.

**Question**

I think I have a configuration but was wanting some advice on the below code. Will it actually work? Is this the best way to do it?

```
<VirtualHost *:80
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /BIPortal>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location>
<Location /BIViwer>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location

<VirtualHost *:8080
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /BIPortal>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location>
<Location /BIViwer>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location
```

**Is the above the way you would do it @Romeo Ninov ?**

Comment: I am not sure apache will work with two ports in VirtualHost definition. Why do not create two virtual hosts, one for port 80 and one for port 8080. And is there any reason to add 3 definitions of `Allow from randomip`

Comment: Also ProxyPass point to the same host which is nonsense for me

Comment: The three separate random ips are place holders for public IPs. The Virtualhosts with two ports I found from this post. https://serverfault.com/questions/480473/apache-proxy-listening-on-multiple-ports

If there is a better way to do this I am all ears just trying to figure this out as I go based on posts I've found. Do you have a better way to do this?

Comment: I personally will recommend to create two virtual hosts, one for port 80 and one for port 8080. Also if your virtual hosts is test123.local this can't be backend to proxy.

Comment: I edited my question to put in the code I was thinking would work. Romeo is the syntax of the above code block correct?

Answer (score 0):

The config of apache should look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80
<Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
</Proxy>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Location /BIPortal>
 ServerName external.host
  ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
 ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
 Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
 </Location>
```

The idea of this config is to make apache act as a proxy for internal host. I name the host of apache `external.host` and the host where the application run `internal.host`

The same config should apply for port 8080

Comment: The above makes sense, however would I be able to do this from a scenario of using it within the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ setting? Also How would I account for each virtual host rule of 80 or 8080 allowing two different context roots. Would it just be adding DocumentRoot = /BIPortal /BIViewer ? or Can you have multiple Doucment roots under the virtual host rules?

Comment: You can do it with different locations (and different proxypass lines)

Comment: I edited my original example to the way I think it would need to be. Does this look correct Romeo?

Comment: @deathscythe272, I edit it to add `BIViwer` proxy records

Comment: My suspected answer is throwing some syntax errors when and if I get them fixed I'll upload the one that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the input from Romeo, the below answer is what I am putting into my /etc/httpd/conf.d/ for the client in question. I'll be changing some of the server names and IP but with Romeo's help I am good not I believe. I'll be testing this over the next few days and go from there thanks so much Romeo :)

```
<VirtualHost *:80
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /BIPortal>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location>
<Location /BIViwer>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIViwer http://internal.host/BIViwer
ProxyPassReverse /BIViwer http://internal.host/BIViwer
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location

<VirtualHost *:8080
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /BIPortal>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
ProxyPassReverse /BIPortal http://internal.host/BIPortal
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location>
<Location /BIViwer>
ServerName external.host
ProxyPass /BIViwer http://internal.host/BIViwer
ProxyPassReverse /BIViwer http://internal.host/BIViwer
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
Allow from randomip
</Location
```